# Using a member method of a MATLAB class as a timer

Tags: matlab, oop, timer

I would like to implement a class which holds a function that will get called by a timer which is started in the constructor.

Two Problems occur:

Firstly, I do not know how to stop the timer within the class. I wrote a static function that stops the timer and a non static function, both of them did not work.

Secondly, I want to use member variables of the class inside the member function that gets called by the timer. However, I can use them but not change them. E.g I want to increment it in each call, it will get incremented in the function but not written to the variable.

```
classdef MyPlottingClass
properties
    n = 0;
    t;
end

methods

    function obj = MyPlottingClass()

        obj.n = 10;
        %initialise timer
        obj.t= timer('ExecutionMode', 'FixedRate','Period', 0.5, 'TimerFcn', {@obj.ptimer});
        obj.t.UserData = 2;
        figure(1)
        xlim([0 30])
        %start timer
        start(obj.t)
    end

    %Time funciton
    function [] =  ptimer(obj,src, event)

       src.UserData = src.UserData + 1;
       obj.n = obj.n  + 1;
       %Test for using a member variable
       display(obj.n);

       if(src.UserData == 31)
           clf
           xlim([0 30])
           hold on
           src.UserData=1;
       end
       figure(1)
       stem(src.UserData,1)
       hold on
    end
end

  %stop function
  methods (Static)
      function [] = stoptimer(obj)
        stop(obj.t) 
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: If you change your class def to inherit handle that should solve your second problem `classdef MyPlottingClass < handle`, still looking at the first one

Comment: So, I tried: `X = MyPlottingClass; pause(5); X.stoptimer` (with stoptimer as a non-static method) and it worked for me

Comment: Thank you really much, it worked - would you like to post it as a real answer instead of a comment so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm happy to, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems you encountered are because matlab classes are value classes by default. In order to make property changes persist, you can make it a handle class by inheriting handle in your class definition:

```
classdef MyPlottingClass < handle
```